# Is there a way to mathematically locate the correct node?

Tags: java

Question from: https://open.kattis.com/problems/numbertree, sourceed from KTH Challenge 2014

[This is how the number tree looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0g7S.png)

I used a for loop to iterate through the input string consisting of 'L' and 'R', and curr to store the current variable being evaluated and previous to store the one before this iteration.

```
if (i == 0) { //first 'L' or 'R'
   if (curr == 'L') { count++; }
   if (curr == 'R') { count +=2 ; }
}
```

Here, if the current character is the same as the previous one, I increase count by 2 to the power of loops passed, and subtract one from that if the current character is not the same as the previous one.

```
else if (curr == prev) { count += (int) Math.pow(2, h); }
else if (curr != prev) { count += (int) Math.pow(2, h)-1;
```

At the end of every loop, I'll equate prev to curr and increment h.

This logic worked for the 3 given inputs, `3 LR`, `3 RRL`, and `2`, which returns `11`, `2`, and `7` respectively.

However it did not pass the hidden test cases. One input I've tried is `3 LLL` 
which should return `8`, but my algorithm returned `3`. `3 LRR` should return 5, but I got 3.

Is there a solution which uses a data structure to obtain the solution, since the problem quotes "perfect binary trees". Appreciate any help in sorting out the kinks in my logic, as well as other solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Please make the code into a MCVE (see help section), and provide example input, and expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Also, at least to me it is unclear what you mean either by "solve it mathematically" or by "is data structure required". But generally speaking, you don't handle text (your input string) "mathematically", at least...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Sorry, first post here on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Why would ```2``` return 7?

Comment: When there's no path. it returns the root, 7

Comment: but the root in the example is 15?

Comment: 15 is for the case of 3 (2^[3+1] - 1). For 2, the root would be (2^[2+1] - 1) = 7. The number given in the input represents the number of levels of the tree (excluding the root)

Answer (score 0):

Being a perfect binary tree, the lowest node at a level x is greater then the sum of 2^k, where k here is the number of nodes from the level x+1 to H. A path 5 RL tells you that you have a node in level 2 on a 5-levels tree, so that node is greater than 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 = 56. Now that we have reduced the tree to H = h(x), we can observe that the path to the node is nothing more than a binary code where L = 0, R =1. We convert this binary code to integer, sum it to the number obtained before and we have the label of the node. A path RL is 10 = 2, and then 5 RL has label 58.

Now, converting this algorithm is very simple as you just have to split the array in two parts, convert the R-L path in binary code and do the math.